# How do I use Compiz's "Scale Window Title Filter"?

Tags: 11.04, unity, compiz, window

I saw [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37722/hard-to-find-one-window-among-many/38589#38589) that described filtering the windows in compiz scale. The feature seems to be [Scale Window Title Filter](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Scale#Scale_Window_Title_Filter).

I have Scale, Scale Addons, and Text turned on in CompizConfig. When I invoke Scale, typing does nothing. Only the arrow keys, Enter, and Esc do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scale Window Title Filter is part of the [compiz-plugins-extra](http://wiki.compiz.org/PluginsExtra) package.

Install this package:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra
```

And then Scale Window Title Filter will show up as a plugin in CompizConfig Settings Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I had [the same problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143589/how-do-i-enable-compiz-scale-window-title-filter-on-12-04/) and found it was because I had been running `ccsm` from a shell instead of from the dash. Once I had launched it from the dash and enabled the correct plugins it began to work. That was in 12.04 under unity 3d though.