# Switch between apps with keyboard only (not ALT+TAB or SUPER+<number>)

Tags: unity, applications-lens

I'm looking for a way to switch between Apps with the keyboard only and not limited to some applications by defining shortcuts.

Gnome3 offers the possibility to switch to (or start) an application by typing the app name. KDE allows this with krunner. The application lens in Unity does not offer this at all: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/1027792

Is there now way to master this very basic and handy functionality with Unity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the compiz 'scale' plugin with

- 'scale window title filter'
- 'scale addon' -> window title (need the 'text' plugin enabled in order to work)

Once activated (meta+w by default), typing part of the title will filter the ones you want, arrows to select.

A very detailed how-to for the installation of the plugin can be found here: [How do I enable the "Scale Window Title Filter" in Compiz on 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143589/how-do-i-enable-the-scale-window-title-filter-in-compiz-on-12-04)

The how-to is for Ubuntu 12.04, but nothing has changed for 12.10.

Comment: Thank you very much! This seems to be the best possible solution without extending the functionality of the application lens.