# Is there a way to add icons to the scale mode?

Tags: compiz, scale-mode

Sometime I have tons of windows open and it'd be really helpful to have their icons attached to them (in the scale view) to make it easier to find what I need.

Is there a way to do that in compiz settings manager?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see [that example](http://mhall119.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/Open.png). It's in **Window Management** -> **Scale** -> Bottom of first tab.

And (before you ask), you can also filter your tons of windows. See [that post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143589/how-do-i-enable-the-scale-window-title-filter-in-compiz-on-12-04) to see what it is and how to use it.