# Issues Upgrading to 13.04 from 12.10 from 12.04

Tags: upgrade

After upgrading, booting into Unity (Ubuntu Default at the login screen) I see just the background image and nothing else, no status bar, and the Windows/Command/Super key does not work as expected. YouTube and other videos play, but no sound. I can only get the Gnome (and it looks to be Gnome 2-ish, definitely not the Gnome 3 I'm used to) shell to work completely.

```
/var/log/Xorg.0.log: http://pastebin.ca/2368675
/var/log/syslog: http://pastebin.ca/2368676

david@poseidon:~$ lspci -v | grep -i vga
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS880 [Radeon HD 4200] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

Any an all help appreciated, and if I've not provided enough detail please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced a similar problem. My problem was the desktop shows background image with no launcher and status bar at the top.

press ctrl+ alt+ t to open the terminal (could not launcher terminal form launcher). type ccsm.

On the left choose desktop. On the right click ubuntu unity plugin.

Check if it is enabled. If not enable the same.

Then reboot sudo reboot. You should see the launcher and the top panel now.

Edit:

While enabling ubuntu unity plugin, required me to intall scale plugin. You can check the same in the below link of how to install.

[How do I enable the "Scale Window Title Filter" in Compiz on 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143589/how-do-i-enable-the-scale-window-title-filter-in-compiz-on-12-04)

For the sound issue check the below link's

[No sound in Ubuntu except at log in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132577/no-sound-in-ubuntu-12-04)

http://www.unixmen.com/2012003-howto-resolve-nosound-problem-on-ubuntu/

Comment: CCSM was not installed, I installed it with aptitude, and attempting to enable Unity plugin says some keybindings conflict with Gnome. Should I proceed anyway?

Comment: yup proceed. should not be a problem i guess

Comment: Okay, this did nothing. :(

Comment: I'm now attempting: https://launchpad.net/~makson96/+archive/fglrx

Comment: Doing this, and the above link has (I think) unity working.

Comment: Also, following the launchpad instructions has sound working.

Comment: @DavidScherer if you got it working post a working solution as an answer.Will help others who visit the post.