# Switching windows - type name of Window

Tags: unity, windows, emacs

In emacs it is possible to switch buffers by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> and you can start typing the name of another buffer, and as you type you can auto-complete the name of buffers which match what you have typed.

In Windows there is a script for AutoHotKeys called [iswitchw](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/30487-iswitchw-cosmetically-enhanced-edition/) which emulates the behaviour of emacs but instead of switching between the buffers in emacs, it allows you to switch between Windows (based on the title of the Window).

Is there any similar tool which allows the user to switch between Windows in Ubuntu/unity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, see [How do I enable the "Scale Window Title Filter" in Compiz on 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143589/how-do-i-enable-the-scale-window-title-filter-in-compiz-on-12-04).

You can then use <kbd>Window Key</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> and start typing to get that effect.

Comment: But I don't have a Windows key... something to do with a sticker with a Linux penguin on it :D

Answer (score 3):

I had been searching for a similar functionality ever since I found the application Switcheroo for Windows that does this same thing. I finally found such a application for Linux, it's called [Rofi](https://github.com/DaveDavenport/rofi), it's a window switcher, application launcher and dmenu replacement. Once you bind a keyboard shortcut to the window launcher mode command of Rofi, you can quickly call it with a keyboard shortcut and start typing a windows name or the name of the application that window belons to and then switch to it.

Comment: is there realy not ogher possibility.in kubunto ? Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04