# How to make alt-tab diplay names of the program/window title?

Tags: 11.04, unity, window-manager

When switching between programs using alt-tab I prefer the program/window title to be displayed as well as the picture of the program.

This is especially useful when I have multiple editor windows open and want to alt-tab to another file. Presently I must try to peer at the content of the small picture of the program ... not at all ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The window border is not displayed this way and it works with <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> instead of <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, but the window title will appear in the middle of the preview window:

1. Start [CompizConfig Settings Manager](http://packages.ubuntu.com/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager] (CCSM)
2. Enable the **Text** and **Scale Addons** plugin
3. In the latter select under the **Appearance** tab **Window Title**
4. In the **Window Title Display** dropdown change to **All Windows**

So Unity only and <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> semi solution. Hope that is enough.

See also:

[Hard to find one window among many](https://askubuntu.com/q/37722/17789)

Comment: This solution is sufficient for my purposes. 
To get behavior more like Alt + Tab (i.e. switching windows on a single desktop) I use I use Shift + Alt + Up-arrow instead of Super + W.