# ALT-TAB showing filenames

Tags: 11.04, unity, application-switcher

I am running Ubuntu 11.04 with the standard unity configuration. I often work with many PDFs open, using evince as my reader. However, from the small visual preview that ALT-TAB provides, it is hard tell which PDF is which. Is there a any different window selection mechanism which shows the filename of open files?

If so, that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Probably not - have a look at this AU question and answer for an alternative solution: http://askubuntu.com/questions/52974/how-to-make-alt-tab-diplay-names-of-the-program-window-title

Answer (score 0):

Compiz' Switcher shows window titles. Start using `compiz --replace`.