# Multi-window switcher - mouseover window title not showing

Tags: 12.04, window-manager, application-switcher

When I have multiple instances of the same program running I see white dots to the left of the launcher icon indicating how many instances I have running. When I click on the icon I see the window switcher kick in and all of the instances appear zoomed out.

I used to be able to mouse over the instances and the window's title would appear which helped to distinguish between the instances. However, at some stage over the last couple of weeks this has disappeared.

Is there a way I can re-activate the display of the window's title on mouse over?

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37722/hard-to-find-one-window-among-many#answer-3966) solved the issue for me. The only additional step I needed was a refresh of unity as I find the auto show/hide functionality of the unity taskbar doesn't work properly after I open the compiz manager. So to refresh unity you can can type:

```
nohup unity --replace &
```

into a terminal or alternatively hit Alt+F2 and type:

```
unity --replace
```

Both yield the same result. For any super noobs the screen will flash dramatically during the refresh so don't worry it will come right after a few seconds.